# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0} {\sqrt[3]{1+{x\over 3}} - \sqrt[4]{1+{x\over 4}} \over 1-\sqrt{1-{x\over 2}}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I'm having trouble evaluating this limit:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} {\sqrt[3]{1+{x\over 3}} - \sqrt[4]{1+{x\over 4}} \over 1-\sqrt{1-{x\over 2}}}$$

mainly because I'm not allowed to use L'Hospital's rule, power expansions or derivatives in general.

The main difficulty as I see it is that the arguments of the roots are different, otherwise I could introduce a new variable $f(x) = y^{12}$ and convert to a rational function.

Comment: Are you supposed to know  equivalents ?

Comment: No Taylor series, as we haven't covered derivatives yet. Equivalents, maybe. What do you have in mind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may prove first that for any $p,q\in\mathbb{N}^+$
$$ \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt[p]{1+\frac{x}{q}}-1}{x}=\frac{1}{pq} \tag{1}$$
holds by rationalization, then use such result to show that your limit equals
$$ \frac{\frac{1}{9}-\frac{1}{16}}{\frac{1}{4}}=\color{red}{\frac{7}{36}}.\tag{2}$$

Comment: That's very nice. I'm going to try it out!

Comment: This is the same solution I was thinking of, but just not separately as you have made it into a result and then using it! I think this is the only non-series, non-LH way!

Comment: @samjoe It is indeed, that's why I'm accepting it. Very nice trick :)

Answer (score 2):

We may use binomial expansions to see that

$$\sqrt[3]{1+\frac x3}=1+\frac19x+\mathcal O(x^2)$$

$$\sqrt[4]{1+\frac x4}=1+\frac1{16}x+\mathcal O(x^2)$$

$$\sqrt{1-\frac x2}=1-\frac14x+\mathcal O(x^2)$$

Thus, we have

$$\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+\frac x3}-\sqrt[4]{1+\frac x4}}{1-\sqrt{1-\frac x2}}=\frac{\frac7{144}x+\mathcal O(x^2)}{\frac14x+\mathcal O(x^2)}=\frac{\frac7{144}+\mathcal O(x)}{\frac14+\mathcal O(x)}\to\frac{7\times4}{144}=\boxed{\frac7{36}}$$

Comment: (+1) Essentially the same approach, but you beat me on time :)

Comment: Sure, but I think this relies on the power expansion if $(1+x)^\alpha$.

Comment: @A.Arredondo Yes, of course it does.  If you wish to avoid, you have to apply a lot of rationalizing and algebra :-/

Answer (score 1):

Separate thw numerator
into two ...-1 terms
and work with them
individually.

A hint:
since
$(1+x)^a \approx 1+ax$,
the numerator
is about
x/9-x/16
and the denominator
is about
1-(1-x/4).

You can also multiply
the num  and den by
$1+\sqrt{1-x/2}$.